# Unable to fire event in Streetview

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm unable to fire event on `pano_change` in the Streetview that is embedded in infowindow. I need to get the array `getLinks()` and `getPosition()` of the object `StreetViewPanorama` each time the user navigates in Streetview infowindow. It is declared as below. I really don't understand why (it works for events on marker and infowindow).

```
//code here

var contentString = '<input type="button" value="Grab this picture" onClick="captureImage()" /> <div id="content" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>';      

//code here

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

//code here//

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    if (pano != null) {
        pano.unbind("position");
        pano.setVisible(false);     
    }
    pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("content"), {
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ANDROID},
        enableCloseButton: false,
        addressControl: false,
        linksControl: false 
    });

    pano.bindTo("position", marker);
    pano.setVisible(true);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'links_changed', XXXX)` and     `google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'position_changed', XXXXX)` in order to get the events.

**Initialization**

```
var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(<element>, panoramaOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'pano_changed', function() {
    // whatever
});

google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'links_changed', function() {
    var links = pano.getLinks();
    for (var i in links) {
        // whatever
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
    var newPos = pano.getPosition();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'pov_changed', function() {
    var newPoV = panorama.getPov();
});
```

Now, every time you have a change in any of those three events (links, pov, position) the relevant function gets called.

Comment: It works with the 2 `google.maps.event.addListener`. The second one in the firt one like this : google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'links_changed', function() {google.maps.event.addListener(pano, 'position_changed', function() {}); var myPosition = this.getPosition(); alert(myPosition); }); Then I can request my new position and also my new panoID with `var panoID = this.getPano();` but not the `StreetViewTileData` object which contains tile information (i need to create the image URL). I think I need first to request `tiles` property from `StreetViewPanoramaData`. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think you should imbricate addListeners. They should be sequential, or the 2nd one might never happen. Updating my answer above to show more clearly.

Comment: Thank you it works properly. I try to check what value the getLinks() return but the array seems to be empty. `for (var i in newLinks) {alert(newLinks[i]);}` display not very intersting informations except [object Object] twice. Don't you think it should normaly return properties `description`, `handling` and `pano` ? (as specified here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#StreetViewLink)

Comment: The docs, mon ami, the docs! :-) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewLink When you debug, don't use alert, use console.log. In a browser you'll be able to expand the Object. The links have 3 properties: .description .heading .pano

Comment: I got it :) I use the `'position_changed'` event to get the new latitude and new longitude and the `'pov_change'` event to monitor zoom, pitch and heading change. Nevertheless it is very strange because after the pov is changed, each move of the mouse cursor (with no click) triggs another pov_change ^^. Then it stops when I finaly click in the pano! I have no idea why it happens because the documentation says that _The point of view changes as the pitch, zoom, or heading changes_. Also Firebug did not assist me a lot because the map didn't load when it is started.

Comment: Firebug is a nice to have :) I realy appreciate your help dda. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: I debug a lot in Safari (WebKit nightly), the Web Inspector saved my life quite a few times. console.log(anobject) enables you to have a peek inside :-)

Comment: I'll try the console.log. I want to modify the `infowindow` object in `event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function()` and replace it with the jQuery UI Dialog object `$('#infowindow')` that is open when clicking the marker. I try with `event.addListener($('#infowindow'), 'domready', function()` and other things but nothing is trigger when the dialog is _domready_. Is there any solution to point to this jQuery dialog object without external pluggin ? thank you.

Comment: make it a different question: I have the answer :)

Comment: done ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688469/how-to-declare-jquery-ui-object-into-addlistener-google-map-event