# How to declare jQuery UI object into addListener Google Map event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

My streetview is embedded into an infowindow box. The panorama is loaded after the infowindow is *domready*, with addListener event.

I would like to modify the object in `event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function()` and replace it with the jQuery UI Dialog object `$('#dialogStreetview')` that is open when the marker is clicked. I try with `event.addListener($('#dialogStreetview'), 'domready', function()` and other things but nothing is trigger when the dialog is domready.

How to point to this jQuery dialog object (jQuery UI event, other jQuery or JS action) ? 
Thank you.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    $( "#dialogStreetview" ).dialog();
});
var pano = null;

//INFOWINDOW

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    if (pano != null) {
        pano.unbind("position");
        pano.setVisible(false);     
    }
    var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("content"), {
        navigationControl: true,
        enableCloseButton: false,
        addressControl: false,
        visible: true,
        linksControl: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `dialogopen` event of the dialog :

```
$("#dialogStreetview").on("dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
```

instead of

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
```

The `dialogopen` event is triggered when the jQuery UI Dialog is opened  .... [docs here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open)

Comment: I search for complicated things when basic is ok. .bind() seems to works too. Tx

Comment: @Florent the `.bind()` method has been replaced by `.on()` - in 1.7.1 the `.bind()` method calls `.on()` -> [See the source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.bind)